# MKPinAnnotationView left button with an Image

Tags: ios, uibutton, mkannotationview

Here is my code:

```
        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        UIButton* leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

        [rightButton setTitle:[(myLocation*)annotation url] forState:UIControlStateApplication];
        [rightButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(showDetails:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

        [leftButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
        customPinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftButton;
```

It works, but the left button appears like a i in a wite circle.
I wish the green car to indicate the availability to obtain directions. 
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, you should create your custom button.

```
UIButton * leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[leftButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[leftButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CAR_IMAGE.PNG"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
customPinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftButton;
```